# import csv file into Google CloudSQL using nodejs Cloud functions

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, etl

Besides streaming a csv file yourself and painstakingly executing inserts for each line of data, is it possible to use the google cloud sdk to import an entire csv file in bulk, from inside a cloud function. I know in gcp console you can go to the import tab, select a file from storage and just import. But how can I emulate this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, one has to parse the `.csv` and generate `SQL` from that; one line in the `.csv` would be represented by one `INSERT` statement. in the first place, you would have to [upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) the file - or pull it into Cloud Functions temporary storage, eg. with `gcs.bucket.file(filePath).download`.

then the most easy might be utilize a library, eg. [csv2sql-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv2sql-lite) - with the big downside, that one does not have full control over the import - while eg. [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) would provide a little more control (eg. checking for possible duplicates, skipping some columns, importing to different tables, whatever).

... and order to connect to Cloud SQL, see [Connecting from Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-cloud-functions).

Comment: thanks so much for confirming what is possible and what's not!! I'll follow this approach then :)

Comment: @yen one could also input CSV with a HTTP trigger; `ETL` (extract, transform, load) is always the same procedure, no matter the environment or language used, no matter where the data comes from - nor where it is written to.